# Error when using "import" statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a following code and get "TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: solc/wrapper" error. I followed these instructions https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#browser-usage to put the code together.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/list.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js"></script>
        <script type="module" defer>
          import * as wrapper from 'solc/wrapper';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please any suggestions where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Does `solc/wrapper` exist relative to the current path?  I imagine that the filename ends with `.js` which is required when using es6 modules in browsers.

Comment: @Evert It does not exist. I thought it will be imported from the libraries declared above the import statement.

Comment: @user3024710 Despite what the documentation you read seems to imply, I'm 90% sure that's not a thing.

Comment: @user3024710 yea that's not how `import` works. import references an actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to install solc npm package

```
npm install solc
```

in order to make the code running.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the problem was, since I've never seen that ES6 import syntax before, but I fixed it by specifying exactly where to import from:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module" defer>
          // debugging
          document.getElementById("runninate").addEventListener("click", function(e){var code=document.getElementById('miniconsole').value; console.log('> ' + code); console.log(eval(code))})

          import * as wrapper from 'https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/soljson-v0.5.0-nightly.2018.10.15+commit.b965fd6e.js';
          const solc = wrapper(window.Module);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="miniconsole" />
        <button id="runninate">Runninate!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not confident enough to say that the syntax was wrong, but considering that they had a typo in the Node.JS example I doubt they tested this.

Note that this fails to import properly because the thing that's being imported doesn't quite work.

Comment: Weird, when I try your code, it says "TypeError: wrapper is not a function". Does the code work for you?

Comment: @user3024710 Yeah... What type _is_ `wrapper` for you?

Comment: @user3024710 Try the `require()` syntax to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @JossClassey That just errored completely, saying that `require` wasn't a thing.

Comment: @user3024710 Did you try it with `soljson-latest.js`?

Comment: @JossClassey yeah, I did use soljson-latest.js

Comment: @wizzwizz4 it says wrapper is a type "object"

Comment: @user3024710 Does it have any properties that look callable? My computer kinda... oh, wait, NoScript is blocking it. I'll see if I can figure out the answer myself!

Comment: @user3024710 Yeah; it's completely failing to import anything useful. I'd call this a bug in `soljs`.

Comment: @user3024710 On a different version, it gets further but then falls flat... I don't think `soljs` actually works yet.